# Create a bottom margin below last item in a Windows Forms listbox control

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a simple Winforms demo app with a single listbox control docked to Fill in the client area of the form. As I add list entries and update the UI, the first entry appears, followed by the second, and so on until the list box client area is completely filled.

As I continue to add entries, the listbox autoscroll property scrolls the listbox so the most recent entry is visible on the last line of the listbox display area. Everything is working fine.

But the last line is uncomfortably close to the bottom of the window, and I would like to control the position of the last line added so that it redisplays somewhere around 3/4 of the height of the listbox. Even 1 line above the bottom would be nicer than tight against the bottom border of the listbox.

I have tried using different numbers for the `listbox1.TopIndex` property, but without success. I don't understand how setting the usual `listbox.TopIndex = listbox1.Items.Count - 1;` value "controls the first line shown in the listbox." From the documentation, setting TopIndex to `Count - 5` should scroll the listbox so that the first visible line is the fifth line from the bottom of the list.

Does anyone know how to control the position of the last listbox line to leave some whitespace at the bottom of the listbox? Thank you.

Comment: Set `IntegralHeight` to false and give the listbox a size that's not a multiple of the height of one item, that will leave a bit of space. If that's not enough then you can "fake" that space, change the listbox `BorderStyle` to `None` add the listbox to a panel with it's `BackgroundColor` set to `Window` and its `BorderStyle` set to `FixedSingle`, in this way you can adjust the listbox inside the panel to leave as much space as you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried earlier to put an empty textbox or list box under my active textbox, but I couldn't get it to work easily with anchoring options. I guess using a panel is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly, styling options for ListView are a bit limited.

You can try this trick. Remove the Listviews borders and place it inside a Panel with appropriate padding:

```
Panel listviewPanel = new Panel();
listviewPanel.BackColor = myListview.BackColor;
listviewPanel.Location = myListview.Location;
listviewPanel.Size = myListview.Size;
listviewPanel.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0,0,0,10);
listviewPanel.BorderStyle = myListview.BorderStyle;
myListview.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
myListview.Parent = listviewPanel;
myListview.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(listviewPanel);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post a snippet. I added a panel in the designer, (Fill) docked the list box in the panel, and it worked perfectly the first time.